# how i can save and fetch the image value in userDefaults in swift

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, nsuserdefaults

Through this code I am animating the image at certain angles but I want to save its value and fetch its value. I am confused how can I save the image value.

```
if totalVal == 250 || totalVal < 500 
{
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    // let imageSave = UserDefaults.standard

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.45, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.needleImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi * 0.40)
    }, completion: nil)

    self.PointsLbl.text = "12 Points"
    defaults.set(self.PointsLbl.text, forKey: "Points")    
} else if totalVal >= 500 && totalVal < 1000 {

    let deff = UserDefaults.standard


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.45, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { ()
         self.needleImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi * 0.60)        
    }, completion: nil)

    self.PointsLbl.text = "30 Points"
    deff.set(self.PointsLbl.text, forKey: "Points")
} else if totalVal >= 1000 && totalVal < 2000  {

    let deff1 = UserDefaults.standard

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.45, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.needleImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi * 0.75)
    }, completion: nil)

    self.PointsLbl.text = "45 Points"
    deff1.set(self.PointsLbl.text, forKey: "Points")            
}
```

Comment: You should never save image in UserDefaults, rather save the image in apps document folder and save the relative path to the image in userdefaults

Comment: i want to save image rotation value not to save image

Answer (score 0):

Save your value to NSUserDefault using “NSStringFromCGPoint”  when animation stop, and fetch your value when you are about to move your image.

NSUserDefault is Singleton you can access it’s value from anywhere by KVC.

Comment: please explain with example of my above code.
Please take a animation statement from above.. Then write save and fetch statement